# Is there different bass pedal sizes?

Tags: drums, drum-kits, bass-drum

I'm new to drumming. I'm an electric guitar player who likes rock and heavy metal, and after playing drums in school and on my spare time in a "band", I'm planning to buy a [Roland TD-11KV kit](http://www.roland.com/products/td-11kv/). I've been searching around a bit for different kits, and I believe this is the one that suites me the best. It's digital, so I can record to my computer and it is quiet, it is made by Roland, which is a quality brand as far as I know, and it is right for my purposes.

The kit doesn't come with a bass pedal, so I'll have to buy one separately. However, when I was searching for one, I found pedals which looked to have different heights. I wonder if all pedals are of the same height, or if they have different heights, and in that case also which height I shall use for the kit i plan to buy ([Roland TD-11KV](http://www.roland.com/products/td-11kv/)).

[This](http://pearldrum.com/products/hardware/drum-pedals/powershifter-eliminator#p-2000c) is the pedal I'm currently looking at.

Comment: If you have no plans of going acoustic, I can recommend the Roland KT-10. It's a kick pedal with its own integrated trigger. Makes less noise than other solution for digital kicks, and it feels natural to play.

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername If possible, I would like to find a cheaper alternative and use the supplied bass drum trigger.

Comment: If a kick trigger is included, then it's better to go with a pedal. As far as I know, kick pedals are make to fit any drum, so unless you go for some special kind of pedal, it should fit.

Comment: Having been down this road myself, I couldn't leave this question without suggesting you consider acoustic drums with mesh heads and some of those zildjian practice/electronic cymbals. Not only will everything feel and sound more like real drums, you'll be able to switch back to real heads any time when you are able to play loud. I like having a drum dial around to make switching and tuning heads a lot easier and faster.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I believe I'll go for a digital kit anyway, because they take up less space, they are easier to record to the computer with, has lots of different sounds, and has built in metronome and coach functions which I believe will help a lot when learning, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Those are all excellent reasons and it sounds like you're making the right choice,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Stated in the comments, any pedal would likely fit the kit you linked to

One thing I'd say first is for Metal and Heavy music you may require a Double Kick pedal. This will still work on the kit you want. I'm not going to lie there is a lot more to a bass pedal than you think. They also take a lot more maintenance.

There are a wide range of pedals that vary in board length, width, Angle, Beater hight, Beater Angle, pedal tension (whether ribbon, Chain, double Chain or Direct drive). There are even different Board styles (longboard and Splitboard)

I can only give you a recommendation from my own personal experience.

A: Stay far away from felt and ribbon pedals (the board is connected to the mechanism by a strip of "Sturdy" material... the soon snap).

B: if you purchase a Chain or double chain pedal, I would recommend Pearl or Ludwig. Always keep the chain oiled up as well as the bearings.

C: Your technique for double pedals if you decide to get one, will change dramatically. It will make it harder to use the Hi Hat pedal take that into concideration.

D: the best thing to do is go to any good drum shop and they will have a full section dedicated to Pedals try a few out and see which takes your fancy.

I personally use a Pearly Eliminator Demon Drive Double pedal with direct Drive. I feel it is very smooth and does not lie to you. If your technique is off it will tell you. With direct drive there is no room for movement between the beater and the pedal board. ( as soon as you start moving the pedal the beater will move towards the bass drum / Pad.

I would also take into consideration that the pedals performance is quite dependant on its price. You get what you pay for in most cases. I was just lucky to have a friend that sold me has pedals for a fraction of its original price.

One more pointer, You can look into how to adjust your pedal to your personal preference too. the springs on most pedals can be tightened or loosened to get better control and/ or speed. Good Luck! hope you get the pedal you want.

One last thing I forgot to tell you, the kick pedal is the most active object on the drum kit, it has the most moving parts, so take that into consideration and see how the pedals move and how well.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. I'll probably not buy double pedals at first, because they are more expensive. I think I'll go for a better single pedal instead. I'll look at it more. Thanks again! **EDIT:** Is the Pearl P-2000C (http://pearldrum.com/products/hardware/drum-pedals/powershifter-eliminator#p-2000c) a good pedal?

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 Yeah it seems quite ample for a starter kit very sturdy might be worth testing. also for double kicks you can get a second hand one for under £100